# Mysql primary key for table with int and varchar field?

Tags: mysql, database-design, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I have a movie table and want to store alternative titles. I'll be storing the alternative titles/aliases in another table. I'm not sure what is the best primary key to use though.

I will have a `movie_id` `INT` field, and an `alias` `varchar(255)` field. Should the primary key be on both fields (since one movie can have more than one alias)? Should I add another field for the primary key instead, for example `alias_id` that just auto increments, but this serves no purpose otherwise. Or does this table need a primary key? Maybe it should just have a unique index on the alias and no primary key is needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your movie_id could be your only PK and auto-incrementing. Then make a FK movie_id in your alternative alias table to match the alt. name with its original title.

```
movie_id  |  Title
--------------------
1     |  "Jaws"
2     |   "Star Trek"
3     |   "Matrix 3"


movie_id   |   Alt_Title
------------------------
1       |   "Death Shark"
1       |   "Tales of the Deep"
3       |   "Neo is Uber"
1       |   "Another Jaws Title"
```

When you make an insert into the alt name table, you will have to make a join on the original title, and pull its movie_id to insert with.

Answer (score 0):

put primary key on id fields in all cases, because the data storage is efficient and match-search operations is quick. if u want to enforce uniqueness use a unique index on the field(s) u want except primary key. primary keys are by default necessary and unique.

Comment: primary key has nothing to do with "efficient" and "quick". It's simply a unique index like any other. It's primary because WE as the programmers/DBAs decide that this key should be the unique identifier for the row it's in, but that's purely a human convenience. There's no internal different between a unique index and a primary index except one little flag to indicate that it's primary. They're both processed identically.

Comment: @Marc: How does the fact that a primary key is an index make it "not efficient"? If someone said, "Making X an index is useless but making it a primary key is efficient", that would be unlikely to be true. I suppose if you mean that you could make a bad primary key and a good "some other index" and then never use the primary key but always use the other index.

Comment: @Jay: sounded to me like hmd was saying a primary key would make things faster. Which is true, but only because the PK is an index. Slapping a PK on a table which doesn't need it is in some ways cargo cult programming.

Comment: @Marc B, the efficiency of data storage is due to the fact that rdb (e.g. mysql) kernel uses primary key to create foreign references. so when u want to reference the table from another, the engine uses an integer which is stored in several bytes to point (in this case uniquely) to main table. @Jay, sure ... but some engines enforce to create a primary key(so called primary index), this is because of internal operations of the engine. theoretically u may use BLOB as a primary, but i recommend to use integers to easily make cross references between tuples!!

Comment: A primary key isn't necessary for a foreign key. You can use any key or combination of keys you want, as long as it/they unique identify the foreign record. Yes, a primary key is the easiest to use for this, because it *IS* the identifier for that record, but if you have an alternate key, you can use that instead.

Comment: @Marc WEll, I don't want to get into a protracted argument, but I still don't see your point. Creating a well-chosen primary key and constructing queries to use it WILL make database accesses more efficient. The fact that a primary key is an index ... so what? If you create a good primary key and then don't construct your queries to use it, okay, I guess that would be pointless. Is that what you're trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, you want to make the movie_id be a foreign key in your alt_title table. Then the simplest thing is probably to create a separate alt_title_id field to be the primary key of the alt_title table. I wouldn't make the title the primary key, because thats awfully long and cumbersome to make a good key.

I'm not sure what you're doing with this data, but my impulse would be to create a single table to hold both primary and alternate titles, and then just have a flag to identify the primary. Assuming you have a bunch of other data about each movie, pull the title out of the basic movie record into a separate table. If you put them in one table, then if you want to search by either primary or alternate title, you just say

```
select whatever
from movie_title
join movie using (movie_id)
where title='Java Forever'
```

If you want to search by just primary title for some reason, fine, you write

```
select whatever
from movie_title
join movie using (movie_id)
where title='Java Forever' and primary=true
```

With two tables, if you want to search by primary title, sure, it's easy. But if you want to search by primary or alternate, you need a union, which is slow and painful. If the query is complex, joining on several other tables or pulling out a bunch of fields, all that extra complexity has to be written twice, in each half of the join.